# How to install java on linux without using RPM?

Tags: java, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running java under a Red Hat Linux 3.4.6 and I have java version 1.4.2 installed somewhere.

I've downloaded and installed the tar.gz file for java jdk7. I've gunzipped the file and also added the installed folder to the path.

The problem is that when I write java -version in the terminal it shows

```
   java version "1.4.2"
```

I'm trying to run a code written in java, but I need the latest version installed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've run the instructions outlined in [oracle's tutorial][1] on how to set the path. It says:

For bash Shell: 
1. Edit the startup file (~/ .bashrc)
2. Modify PATH variable:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin
```

3. export PATH
4. Save and close the file
5. Open new Terminal window
6. Verify the PATH is set properly

   % java -version

Now when I run

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ echo $PATH
```

eveything seems to be fine, but when I type java -version a terrible error appears:

```
Error dl failure on line 875
Error failed /opt/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so, because
/lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC-2.4' not found 
(required by /opt/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shell searches for the executables in the directories listed in your PATH variable.
See

```
echo $PATH
```

If you are running the bash shell, then type the command

```
type -a java-version
```

and

```
type -a java
```

You will then see all directories where bash is finding these two executables.
You will have either to prepend your new jdk7 installation directory (the bin directory in there!) to your PATH, or start java giving the absolute path to the version you want.

If you installed jdk7 under /usr/local/jdk7, then start the java executable in there typing

```
/usr/local/jdk7/bin/java
```

or prepend /usr/local/jdk7/bin to your PATH variable with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk7/bin:$PATH
```

Hope this helps.